# Crisis in my understanding of probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, terminology, paradoxes

If I were to roll a die, what would ​be the probability of getting $2$? Certainly it would be $\dfrac 16$ (because there are $6$ numbers and sample space contains 6 numbers)
 But I think we can look at it another way. 
We need $2$ right? and from $1-6$ there is only one number which is $2$ i.e. $2$. If I were to roll there would essentially be two types of numbers ie. one which is $2$ and one which is not ie $1,3,4,5,6$. So there are two basic outcomes.
P(E) = number $2$÷total outcomes ie $2$.
P(E)= $\dfrac 12$
So why is the probability $\dfrac 16$(when it is clear that the outcome we desire, can either happen or not happen.) Shouldn't the probability be $\dfrac 12$ instead, why not?

Comment: The probability of getting 2 may be $1/6$ or $1/2$ depending on the chosen probability model.

Comment: You need to decompose these into *simple* events. What **exactly** happens, and when? A simple event is one that *cannot* be broken down further. The event $\overline E$ can be broken down further since there are $5$ possibilities where you don't get $2$.

Comment: This is a perfect chance to remind that $Pr(E)=\frac{|E|}{|S|}$ is **only** valid when all outcomes in the sample space $S$ are equally likely to occur.  In situations where the outcomes are not known to be equally likely then you may *not* use the above and must instead approach more carefully.

Comment: “Crisis”? ${}{}$

Comment: Either you're going to win the lottery, or you're not going to win the lottery. Is your theory that you win the lottery 50% of the times you play it?  Here, here's 100 lottery tickets, all with different numbers on them.  Either every number wins, or not every number wins. Is your theory that 50% of the time, every one of those hundred tickets is a winner?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: A crisis is by definition a moment in time when an important change will happen, the consequences of that change will be far-reaching, and it is difficult to go back to undo the change; typically it is applied to disease -- where the change will either kill or heal the patient -- or to historical events -- where the change will cause political or social upheaval. But it is perfectly reasonable, if somewhat histrionic, to apply it to one's understanding of a subject. Either the OP will resolve the crisis and understand probability, or they will fail to and never understand it.

Comment: If you insert some extra weight on the 5 face and learn to roll the die so as to take advantage of that off-center weight, maybe you _can_ roll a 2 with probability 1/2. Maybe even with probability greater than 1/2. (This touches on the fallacy mentioned in one of the answers: when should we assume a set of events are equally likely?)

Comment: Whatever you do, do not engage in any gambling or skill games such as poker that have random elements until you have got this figured out.  In the meantime, consider that the next person you talk to will either be Beyonce or it will be someone else.  Do you think the next person you speak with will be Beyonce with 50% probability?

Comment: Oh wow, that is literally the same question as the suggested one from three years ago.

Answer (score 45):

The probability is $\frac{1}{6}$ because there are $6$ elements in the sample space that are *all equally likely*.

If we take a sample space of $2$ and not $2$, then there are $2$ elements in the sample space, but they are *not equally likely*.

The classic example is that you don't have a $50\%$ chance of winning the lottery because the two options are "win" and "don't win".

Comment: "you don't have a 50% chance of winning the lottery" what a bad news... :(  But the example is very good :).

Answer (score 25):

This is actually a good instance of a really common logical fallacy. I'm not sure if the fallacy has any particular name -- one might call it the "equal likelihood fallacy," perhaps. The fallacy is assuming that events in a probability space have equal likelihood, even though they may not.

In general, one requires an affirmative reason to state that events have equal likelihood. When I roll a die, I can say that the chance of it rolling on any particular side is $1/6$ because (a) it's symmetric, so it shouldn't have any geometric bias in favor of one side over another, and (b) my experience confirms (or rather, doesn't dispute) this assumption. Similarly, when I draw a card from a well-shuffled deck, the word "well-shuffled"  means there shouldn't be any particular favoritism toward any card; that is, all cards are equally likely.

But absent a reason like that, it's dangerous to say that events are equally likely, and it's very often false. If I flip 4 coins, then the number of those coins that could come up heads will be 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. However, it is *not* true that each of those has a 20% chance of occurring; instead, having 2 coins come up heads is significantly more likely than the other possibilities, while 0 and 4 are the least likely.

For a good example of this fallacy in action, I'll refer you to this clip from the Daily Show: http://www.cc.com/video-clips/hzqmb9/the-daily-show-with-jon-stewart-large-hadron-collider
The fallacy can be seen at about the 2:38 mark, and the proper rebuttal is at about the 5:30 mark. I'll warn you that the video is perhaps mildly vulgar and not safe for work (strong language). However, the video gives some *hilarous* examples of mistake made in the argument you supplied.

Comment: Thanks and don't worry I'm still in tenth standard. Too early for office.

Comment: Perhaps not safe for class, then. :) I'm also not sure if it will be regionally-locked; it wouldn't shock me if it's for US viewers only, so my apologies if it is.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery LOL. Thanks for the video!

Comment: A related fallacy: When the Fields medal was awarded to Perelman for proving the Poincaré conjecture, [Steven Colbert complained](http://www.cc.com/video-clips/xr6owy/the-colbert-report-cheating-death---fields-medal) about not getting one for himself: "They gave out four of these! So I had a one in four chance!"

Answer (score 5):

The probability of not getting a $2$ is far more likely than getting a $2$. Hence, you can't just say that since getting a $2$ is one of two possible outcomes, its probability is $\frac{1}{2}$, for that assumes each of the possible outcomes is equally likely.

If you want to think about this problem in terms of the two possible outcomes of getting a $2$ versus not getting a $2$, you need to take their respective probabilities into account:

$$P(2) = \frac{P(2)}{P(2) + P(not \ 2)} = \frac{\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6}} = \frac{\frac{1}{6}}{1} =\frac{1}{6}$$

Crisis averted!

Answer (score 1):

Assume an omnipotent creature approaches me and tells me that it had decided the following: it will either kill me, or all the other $7.5$ billion people in earth. And it will decide what course of action to take, by flipping a fair coin, i.e. a coin where its side has the same probability of landing, $1/2$. If it lands heads, it will take my head. Otherwise, it will take $7.5$ billion heads. Here the probability of me dying is $1/2$.

The "elementary events" here are indeed just two, and *we have decided* to give to each equal probability, even though their physical reality is rather non-comparable (surely, even for an omnipotent creature killing $7.5$ people will take more energy and time than killing just one person).

But assume now that the omnipotent creature has created a fair die with $7.5 \text{bn} +1$ sides, and it will roll this die in order to determine whether it will kill me or it will kill the other $7.5$ billion. If the die comes up $1$, it will kill me. If it does not come up $1$, it will kill all the others. Here the probability of me dying is $1/(7.5 \text{bn} +1)$, a bit lower than in the previous situation.

The physical actions that may take place in both situations are the same: either I will die, or everybody else will.

But the allocation of probability to these two events is quite different in the above two scenarios, and it should be obvious that any other "probability scenario" could be constructed by the omnipotent creature... what does that tells us about the concept of probability?

Comment: "Bit" lower you say?

Comment: @user167920 Yeah, it's all a matter of perspective I guess :). Rather it is  somewhat more than just "bit" lower.

Answer (score -1):

> P(E) = number 22÷total outcomes

The problem in the construction you have created is that the selection part (choose a side out of 6, the set {1,2,3,4,5,6}) doesn't match the total outcomes part (choose from the set {2, not 2}).